# Why JVM executes same program faster over time when launched?

Tags: jvm, java

I have written a simple SUDOKU solver. To roughly test the performance I'm using simple *System.currentTimeMillis* calls.

I have prepared a set of initial sudoku configuration in text file. The program reads the file and solves each sudoku configuration. When running the tests I have noticed that the first 3-4 solve runs are really slower than the rest and by slower I mean by order of magnitude.

There is sample pseudo-code snippet:

```
main(){
     while(file has lines){
         configuration = readLine();
         Solver s = new Solver(configuration);

         now1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
         s.solve();
         now2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

         System.out.print(now2 - now1);
     }
}
```

I measure only *solve()* method, so IO is not a problem, I even hardcoded some data into program - still first few slower. The difficulty of puzzle is not an issue as well I have tried different permutations and difficulties of configuration and always the same - first few are slower.

My question is - why is that and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Is there another metric you can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *supposed* to happen.  The JIT compiler optimizes code that gets called more often as your program runs for longer.

This only reflects the general fact that the technique you're using to test performance simply isn't reliable in Java.

Comment: Okay, first: Is there any way to force compiler optimization from the very beggining?
Second: "How to test performance the "right" way?"

Comment: Not from the _very_ beginning.  You can make it happen faster, but that's actually likely to slow your program down, because it'll optimize other code that's not worth optimizing.  If you want reliable performance metrics, the most basic thing you can do is to run your program for a couple seconds of warmup before you start measuring, but the best thing to do is to use something like [Caliper](http://caliper.googlecode.com) that understands the JVM and takes care of all that for you.

Comment: For reference, it's [-XX:CompileThreshold](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).

Answer (score 2):

In Practice, Methods are not compiled by `JIT` the first time they are called by `JVM`. For each method, the `JVM` maintains a `call count`, which is incremented every time the method is called. The `JVM` interprets a method until its `call count` exceeds a `JIT compilation threshold`. Therefore, **often-used** `methods` are `compiled` soon after the `JVM` has started , and **less-used** `methods` are compiled much later, or not at all. This `JIT compilation Threshold` helps the `JVM` start quickly.

> So, the **busiest methods** of java program are always optimized most
>   *aggresively* which increases its execution speed each time it is called by program.

[**Here**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/understanding/jit_overview.html) is the Source for above information.

Answer (score 1):

In performance testing engagements we'd always run the system being tested for a while to let it reach a steady state.  Only then would we start the performance metrics.  You might try the same: run the solve() method a number of times before capturing your metrics.